# How to access an image from inside the function using Tkinter and Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Some things went not quite how I expected.

I am currently developing a GUI via Tkinter in Python. The idea is to create an interface, which allows me to select 2 jpg or png formatted pictures from my computer, resize them and show in two separate square frames. Once it is done, there is a third frame with the third button underneath, which supposed to start an animation (sequential image transitions) with the further involvement of pictures 1 and 2. I have no problem with importing these images in frames, however, when I try to access my global image variable inside the function (which is bound to the button) in order to convert an image to the array of pixels, the compiler finds no value stored in the variable.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Canvas
from numpy import asarray
import numpy as np

window = Tk()
window.title("Image Transitions")
window.geometry("1200x800")
window.config(background="CornflowerBlue")
window.maxsize(1200, 800)

title1 = Label(window, text="Image 1", width=20)
title1.place(x=180, y=175)
title1.configure(bg="CornflowerBlue")

title2 = Label(window, text="Image 2", width=20)
title2.place(x=530, y=175)
title2.configure(bg="CornflowerBlue")

title3 = Label(window, text="Image Transitions", width=20)
title3.place(x=880, y=175)
title3.configure(bg="CornflowerBlue")

button1 = Button(window, text="Upload Image 1", width=20, command=lambda:browse_Image1())
button1.place(x=180, y=510)

button2 = Button(window, text="Upload Image 2", width=20, command=lambda:browse_Image2())
button2.place(x=530, y=510)

canvas1 = Canvas(window, width=300, height=300)
canvas1.pack()
canvas1.configure(bg="LightSkyBlue")
canvas1.place(x=100, y=200)

canvas2 = Canvas(window, width=300, height=300)
canvas2.pack()
canvas2.configure(bg="LightSkyBlue")
canvas2.place(x=450, y=200)

canvas3 = Canvas(window, width=300, height=300)
canvas3.pack()
canvas3.configure(bg="LightSkyBlue")
canvas3.place(x=800, y=200)

def browse_Image1():
    global image_first

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    initialdir = "/",
    title = "Select a File",
    filetypes = (("2D - JPG", "*.jpg*"), ("2D - PNG", "*.png*"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    
    img = Image.open(filename)
    img = img.resize((300, 300))
    image_first = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

    label = Label(window, image=image_first)
    label.pack()
    label.place(x=100, y=200)

def browse_Image2():
    global image_second
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    initialdir = "/",
    title = "Select a File",
    filetypes = (("2D - JPG", "*.jpg*"), ("2D - PNG", "*.png*"), ("all files", "*.*")))

    img2 = Image.open(filename)
    img2 = img2.resize((300, 300))
    image_second = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)

    label = Label(window, image=image_second)
    label.pack()
    label.place(x=450, y=200)

ImageA_Width, ImageA_Height = image_first.size
data_A_norm = asarray(image_first) / 255.0
data_B_norm = asarray(image_second) / 255.0

window.mainloop()
```

As far as I understand, in order to access an image stored in a variable I need to call this function. However, in my case it is prohibited, as the “Select file” window will be called again.

I need to somehow do both things:

1. Execute the command: choose and import images by pressing button.
2. Get access to the imported images stored in variables to perform animations.

How can I do both?

Comment: Why are there two buttons to select images? [askopenfilenames](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames)

Comment: This is not a working example, your variable is not just empty it is not initialized and throws an error. `Traceback (most recent call last): line 81, in <module> ImageA_Width, ImageA_Height = image_first.size NameError: name 'image_first' is not defined`

Do you have a working example?

Comment: Consider posting a [mre].